# Decimal point removed from decimals in a Serialized XML

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, decimal

I'm using `XmlSerializer` with classes created from a `xsd` using `xsd.exe`. It has worked fine for months.

Now I'm receiving reports that in some cases the created xml file has all decimals serialized without a decimal point, e.g. 123.45 is serialized as 12345.

I haven't been able to reproduce the problem, but I'm suspecting it may be related to localization.

This is my first C# project, so I may be overlooking something basic.

Could localization cause this problem?
How can I make the serialization process locale independent?

Any idea of something else that could cause this problem?

Comment: "I haven't been able to reproduce the problem" - that's your first step.

Comment: @mitch True. Tomorrow I'm going to visit the site where the problem is happening, but want to have ideas of what to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some countries they use a comma as decimal separator, and the dot to separate thousands, so your hunch could be true. If you're using a `float` or another data type that holds decimals, `XmlSerializer` should not in any case throw away the decimals. However if in such a country you read The Xml without specifying a culture, it might ignore the dot.

So Xml serialized in one country and deserialized in another country would cause problems if you don't specify something like `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The "deserialization" part was actually some custom code reading values from a text file. There were some `.ToDecimal()` there, I added `InvariantCulture` and that seems to solve the problem in a quick test.